# Puppeteer crawler data export

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer function that goes to a certain page with template literals, and reads the content of the given table.
How could I send the array that I have from the website to my server so I could fetch it via an API?
Thank you!

The code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const today = new Date();

let ma = today.getFullYear() + '.' + 0 + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + today.getDate() + '.';


const url = `https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyam-tablazat?deviza=rbCustom&devizaSelected=ZAR&datefrom=${ma}&datetill=${ma}&order=1&customdeviza%5B%5D=EUR&customdeviza%5B%5D=USD&customdeviza%5B%5D=GBP`

async function getTable() {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url);

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {

    const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr td'))
    return tds.map(td => td.innerText)
  });

  
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data[0])
  await browser.close();
};

getTable();
```

This is the server with only one route

```
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();
app.use(cors())

const devizak = [**Data from puppeteer**]

app.get("/devizak", cors(), function (req, res, next) {
    if (devizak.length < 1) {
        return null
    } else {
        res.json([devizak])
    }
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("App is listening on port 5000");
})
```

Comment: You want to send `data` your API? Make a request with axios or node-fetch to your endpoint.

Comment: Do you already have a server which is running? Then setup a location say `/test-data` and use the native javascript `fetch` method.

Comment: @SilvanBregy The "native" fetch doesn't exist in node, though it can be installed via [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Comment: you can return `data` from the `getTable` function and then use it in node or send it via `fetch` in the function itself

Comment: @reyno mm, yes.. So as mentioned use node-fetch or axios^^

Comment: I have updated my question so it's more readable and maybe clearer, sorry and thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context/relationship between this script and your server code this is more difficult to answer, but:

Assuming your server is RESTful, I would recommend sending the array as a POST request to your server with the native [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or a third party HTTP library like [Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro). For example:

```
const Axios = require('axios')
const serverURL = /* Your server URL here */

// Get the array from your async function
getTable()
  .then((yourArray) => {

    // Send to your server
    Axios.post(serverURL, yourArray)

  })
```